# How to create 1 shimmer gradient with color in 10 button swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to create a view that has 10 buttons to create just 1 gradient animation that runs over 10 view buttons but can't. Only make a gradient for a button. Does anyone have any way?

[image]

This my code. I tried it but I want it to gradient the whole color of the title button

```
 let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds//path.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.magenta.cgColor, UIColor.cyan.cgColor]
    let shapeMask = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect: button1.frame)
    path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: button2.frame))
    path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: button3.frame))


    shapeMask.path = path.cgPath
    gradient.mask = shapeMask

    let whiteMask = CAShapeLayer()
    whiteMask.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    let whitePath = UIBezierPath(rect: button1.frame.inset(by: insets))
    whitePath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: button2.frame.inset(by: insets)))
    whitePath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: button3.frame.inset(by: insets)))
    whiteMask.path = whitePath.cgPath
    self.bgView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    self.bgView.layer.addSublayer(whiteMask)
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Please view my code. Thank you!

Comment: What's the reason that you add sublayer "whiteMask" over sublayer "gradient".  Remove `self.bgView.layer.addSublayer(whiteMask)` will display entire gradient among these 3 buttons without white colour.

Comment: Thank @PeterGuo. that's just a test, if you remove self.bgView.layer.addSublayer (whiteMask), it still doesn't have the "title buttons" gradient

Comment: what is the required view you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your buttons are separate, therefore each gets their own dedicated gradient. What you'll need to do is create separate 'stops' along the gradient for the boundaries of the buttons, then, if animating the gradient, move the stops as the animation progresses. An alternative is to create a single background view with the gradient, then add the buttons to this background view. Add a single mask with different sections to the background view to reflect the position of the buttons within the view.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is enough to show what's required...

[image: Gradient example]

Comment: Thank JonJ But it same my code. I want gradient include title button : button 1, button 2 ... it is name button.